# ContentPresenter in RadTabControl only shows once

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have a RadTabControl with 9 tabs, and each one use a ContentPresenter binding the same property(my view):

```
<telerik:RadTabItem Header="Tab1">
                    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      Content="{Binding ContenidoNota,
                                                        Mode=TwoWay}" />
</telerik:RadTabItem>
<telerik:RadTabItem Header="Tab2">
                    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      Content="{Binding ContenidoNota,
                                                        Mode=TwoWay}" />
</telerik:RadTabItem>
<telerik:RadTabItem Header="Tab3">
                    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      Content="{Binding ContenidoNota,
                                                        Mode=TwoWay}" />
</telerik:RadTabItem>
```

When I change the tab I send the tab's index through an event.

The thing is that when I change through tabs for first time the `contentpresenter` works fine, but when I click back in any tab the `contentpresenter` displays nothing, only shows the `contentpresenter` in the last tab clicked.

This only happens when I use the same binding content in `ContentPresenter`.

Any idea?

In my VM:

```
ContenidoNota = new VistaXaml(new      VistaXamlViewModel(this,this.componentContainer,this.regionManager,this.eventAggregator));
 public UserControl ContenidoNota
    {
        get
        {
            return contenidoNota;
        }

        set
        {
            contenidoNota = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ContenidoNota);
        }
    }
```